# ¿Cómo evitar que gpg guarde mi contraseña de cifrado en linux?

Tags: linux, encriptación, cifrado, gpg

Al cifrar un archivo con:

```
gpg -c archivo.tar
```

me pide una contraseña, pero a la hora de desencriptar el archivo con:

```
gpg archivo.tar.gpg
```

ahí se desencripta sin pedir contraseña, solo pide contraseña si he reiniciado mi sistema

Answer (score 2):

Problema solucionado.

basta con poner:

```
gpg -c --no-symkey-cache archivo.txt
```